# Non-roots of unity auxillary constants in a group?

Tags: universal-algebra

Let $A$ be a set, together with a set $F$ of n-ary operations on A, which may include constants of $A$ as 0-ary operations. A set $G$ of operations on $A$ is said to be auxillary with respect to the algebra $(A,F)$ if $G$ is disjoint from $F$ and the equational identities of $(A,F)$ generate the equational identities of $(A, F \cup G)$. For example, in $(\mathbb R, +)$, every {$r$} where $r$ is a nonzero real, is an auxillary set. My question is, take a group $G$ in the signature {$*$}. Suppose $g$ is not an n-th root of unity. Is {$g$} an auxillary set with respect to $(G, *)$. I apologize if the question is too long, but I would be VERY surprised to see a counterexample.

Comment: Perhaps if you take $g$ in the center of the group, the identity $\forall x: g*x = x*g$ would not follow from the identities of $G$. But it seems that the same reasoning would work for a root of the unity. For instance, why does $g^{2n}=g^n$ follows from the identities of $G$?

Comment: I am not sure how to interpret your question, since in universal algebra, a group is usually defined with the signature $(*, 1, {}^{-1})$.

Comment: @J.E.Pin I mean the reduct in the signature {*}.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf For example in the multiplicative group of the reals, (x * -1 * -1) = x does not follow from the identities of the multiplicative group. The only identities are those that can be generated by the associative and commutative identities.

Comment: So, a non-root-of-the-unity element of the center of a non-commutative group should be a counterexample (as I indicated above). Please correct me if I'm wrong.